# How to find and copy files with spaces?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I am trying to find `mp3` files in any subdirectories and to copy them, for example, in the current directory. Here is the command I tried:

```
find . -name *.mp3  -ls | gawk '{printf("cp %s .\n", $11);}'
```

The `find` command list all the files correctly escaped, but `gawk` seem to have problems with it. The `find` command lists for example the following file

```
8132326 7392 -rw-r--r--   1 alexander alexander  7566180 Nov 27 20:22 ./For\ The\ Kids\ EP\ [12_\ Vinyl\ EP\ -\ DP003]/01\ A1\ For\ the\ Kids.mp3
```

while the `gawk` command sees as `$11` the string

```
./For
```

instead of

```
./For\ The\ Kids\ EP\ [12_\ Vinyl\ EP\ -\ DP003]/01\ A1\ For\ the\ Kids.mp3
```

Why is that? And how to handle this correctly (with or without `gawk`)?

Comment: I'm just curious, how did you come up with the original command? Did you find that in a tutorial somewhere? It's a little convoluted, and I'm just trying to find out how to make Bash examples on the Internet better as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command is

```
 find /folder/to/be/searched -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec cp "{}" /target/folder \;
```

It is simpler, hence fewer chances for errors.  Only thing: remember to use absolute paths, not relative ones.